# Missing image size

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have added a couple of custom sizes to my wordpress environment with the following code:

```
add_image_size( "maximal", "1900" );
add_image_size( "desktop", "1400" );
add_image_size( "tablet", "900" );
add_image_size( "smalltablet", "700" );
add_image_size( "mobile", "500" );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

but when I call an image, the 1900px version is always missing:

```
<img src="test.laurentwillen.be/pixel.gif" class="attachment-mobile size-mobile wp-post-image" alt="Xiaomi Mi 8 Lite test, avis et prix" srcset="https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/11/Xiaomi-mi8-lite-test-avis-review-500x156.jpg 500w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/11/Xiaomi-mi8-lite-test-avis-review-300x94.jpg 300w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/11/Xiaomi-mi8-lite-test-avis-review-768x240.jpg 768w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/11/Xiaomi-mi8-lite-test-avis-review-1024x320.jpg 1024w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/11/Xiaomi-mi8-lite-test-avis-review-1400x438.jpg 1400w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/11/Xiaomi-mi8-lite-test-avis-review-900x281.jpg 900w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/11/Xiaomi-mi8-lite-test-avis-review-700x219.jpg 700w" width="100%">
```

In the end I see the following formats in my images:
300, 500, 700, 768, 900, 1024, 1400

I should probably remove the old WP sizes but I really don't get why I'm not getting the 1900px format even if I visit a page on a 2k screen. The consequence is that people with a resolution around 1600 and more get lower quality images.

Do you have any idea of what I should do to have those 1900px images ? I already regenerated my thumbnails.

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: Are you sure that the original uploaded image started out as larger than 1900px? I believe that if the original was smaller than 1900, the larger just wouldn't be made.

Comment: @JakeParis Yes, I upload all my images with a minimum width of 2500px

Comment: @user3638239 maybe your server is not able to create such big image - to resize an image it has to store both images (original and resized) in memory - maybe it exceeds that limit. Are there any entries in log file?